# How do I load a x509 keypair from a pkcs12 store?

Tags: go, ssl, server, x509, pkcs#12

I have a script that creates a PKCS12 store on a server via OpenSSL.  I am developing a TLS/SSL server in Go and need to load the key pair from the created PKCS12 store.  How do I pull the keypair from the PCKS12 store and load them?

Here is my code snippet, which is giving me an error:

```
src/server.go:59:19: cannot use cert (type interface {}) as type []byte in argument to ioutil.WriteFile: need type assertion
src/server.go:60:19: cannot use key (type *x509.Certificate) as type []byte in argument to ioutil.WriteFile
```

```
 import "golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12"


 // Read byte data from pkcs12 keystore
 p12_data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../identify.p12")
 if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
 }

 // Extract cert and key from pkcs keystore
 cert, key, err := pkcs12.Decode(p12_data, "123456")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

//Write cert and key out to filepath
ioutil.WriteFile("cert.pem", cert, 777)
ioutil.WriteFile("key.pem", key, 777)

log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
cer, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

Comment: Judging from the error messages you a) should swap the cert and key variables, and b) don't need to load the keypair with the tls package because pkcs12.Decode already does that. You just have to initialize a value of type tls.Certificate directly. If you want concrete help let us know which package pkcs12 is.

Comment: I added the import so you van see the pkcs12 package.  I'm a bit confused by what you are saying.  Could you show ma an example in the form of an answer rather than in a comment please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load the keypair with the tls package because pkcs12.Decode already does that. Simply initialize a value of type tls.Certificate:

```
p12_data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../identify.p12")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

key, cert, err := pkcs12.Decode(p12_data, "123456") // Note the order of the return values.
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

tlsCert := tls.Certificate{
    Certificate: [][]byte{cert.Raw},
    PrivateKey:  key.(crypto.PrivateKey),
    Leaf:        cert,
}
```

Quoting [the documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12#Decode):

> This function assumes that there is only one certificate and only one private key in the pfxData; if there are more use ToPEM instead.

The documentation contains an example that shows how to use ToPEM to initialize a tls.Certificate.